Were the Levitical services a form of worship or not?
The word for worship (Heb: חוה; Grk: προσκυνεω) is only used once in Leviticus, and this verse (Lev 26:1) refers to idol worship rather than Levitical worship. I have yet to find a link between worship and sacrifice, and Hosea 6:6 seems to reinforce this when it says, "I desire steadfast love and not sacrifice, the knowledge of God rather than burnt offerings" (ESV). It seems to me that sacrifice might only be for a reconciliatory purpose and not necessarily for worship. Are my suspicions correct, or am I missing anything?

The premise of this question is wrong. The text of Lev 26:1 says לא־תעשו לכם אלילם ופסל ומצבה לא־תקימו לכם ואבן משכית לא תתנו בארצכם להשתחות עליה כי אני יהוה אלהיכם, the word you're referring to is להשתחות. The word in your post doesn't appear here. It's a word meaning life and also happens to be Chava/Eve's name (from Adam and Eve)

It seems the root of הִֽשְׁתַּחֲוֺ֖ת's could be שָׁחָה or חוה. Logos Bible Software identifies the root as חוה. The LXX translates the word here as προσκυνεω, and this is the word used to translate חוה elsewhere. Lev 26:1 serves as only as an example, so the premise of the question still stands regardless of who's right. In any case, חוה and προσκυνεω are still not represented in priestly rites as far as I know. Do you have any thoughts?

Also, חיה is the word for life, חוה is the word for worship/bowing. C.f. DBL Hebrew 2649 and 2556.

The pertinent verb in Lev 26:1 is שָׁחָה (shachah) which means to bow and/or worship.  In the Torah this occurs:

Gen 18:2, 19:1, 22:5, etc (23 times)
Ex 4:31, 11:8, 12:27, 18:7, etc) (12 times)
Lev 26:1 (once)
Num 22:31, 25:2 (twice)
Deut 4:19, 5:9, 8:19, 11:16, 17:3, 26:10, 29:26, 30:17 (8 times)

Most of these are warnings against worship/bowing to false gods.  A few record the act of bowing before the true God of heaven such as Ex 4:31, 11:8, 24:1, 33:10, 34:8, Num 23:31, Deut 26:10, etc.
It is only Deut 26:10 that makes any connection between bowing and a ceremonial act:

And now, behold, I have brought the firstfruits of the land that You,
O LORD, have given me.” Then you are to place the basket before the
LORD your God and bow down before Him.

Thus, we find an important teaching - the ceremonial and sacrificial system was not to define worship!  Indeed, as the OP points out, the ceremonial system had been misunderstood and abused and did not provide propitiation but only symbolized the sacrifice of Jesus (yet to come), eg, Isa 1:10-17, Ps 40:6-8, 51:16, 17, 1 Sam 15:22, Hos 6:6, Prov 15:8, 21:3, Jer 6:20, Micah 6:6-8, etc.  Jesus used some of these verses to teach the superiority of the moral and ethical requirements over the ceremonial rules.  Matt 9:9-12, 12:2-8, 9-14, 23:23, 24, Mark 12:33.
Thus, the ceremonial system was a was a teaching system to inculcate the plan of salvation, Heb 9:11-14, Col 2:16, 17, not a system of worship.

Excellent observations! Before we can consider any subject such as worship, it's critical that we don't confuse popular images with the definition used at the time!

So bowing down is automatically worship? (1 Chronicles 29:20)

@JamesAjiduah - Please do now put words in my mouth - I did not say that and was careful to avoid just that.  Worship often involves bowing but bowing does not always imply worship.

Your definition of shachah led to that conclusion.

This claim is backed up by the Bible. Here are the biblical elements that support it:

The Levites as a tribe consecrated to God

Origin and role of the Levites: The Levites are descended from Levi, one of Jacob's sons, and are consecrated to serve God in place of Israel's firstborn. This choice is confirmed in Numbers 3:5-13, where God declares that the Levites belong to Him.
They are separated for service in the Tabernacle and Temple, and their specific duties are detailed in several passages, notably 1 Chronicles 23:28-32.


Liturgical and sacred roles

Transporting the Tabernacle and sacred objects: Before the Temple was established, the Levites were responsible for dismantling, transporting and reassembling the Tabernacle during wilderness journeys (Numbers 4:1-33).
Helping the priests: They assisted the priests (from the line of Aaron) in ritual tasks such as maintaining the Tabernacle, caring for the sacred utensils and preparing the sacrifices (Numbers 8:5-26).


Temple ministry

After Solomon built the Temple, the Levites continued their service by providing singing, music and other cultic functions (2 Chronicles 5:12-14, 2 Chronicles 29:25-30).
They were also responsible for teaching the Law to the people (2 Chronicles 17:7-9, Nehemiah 8:7-8).


Worship and sacrifice

Although only the priests could offer sacrifices, the Levites had an assisting role in organizing the sacrifices and maintaining the ritual purity of the sanctuary (Leviticus 1-7, Ezekiel 44:11-14).




You have answered the question twice, each answer in contrast to the other. In addition, the format of this seems a lot like ChatGPT. Can you clarify the source of your information?

It is true that I sometimes use ChatGPT to easily find certain references or parallels. Is it forbidden please?

I shouldn’t need to go to Stackexchange if I can ask ChatGPT. Generating an AI answer is generally disfavored in these environments.

Paul would answer "yes" to this question.

Therefore, I urge you, brothers and sisters, in view of God’s mercy, to offer your bodies as a living sacrifice, holy and pleasing to God—this is your true and proper worship. (Romans 12:1)

Here Paul uses sacrificial language to describe giving one's life to God, and defines this as true worship.
Other prayers presuppose this:

May my prayer be set before you like incense; may the lifting up of my hands be like the evening sacrifice. (Psalm 141:2)

Here, the Psalmist asks God to treat his prayer as a sacrifice, implying that sacrifice was considered the normal means of rendering service to God.

These verses use metaphor and simile to convey a relationship between worship and sacrifice. Have you identified any verses where a direct relationship is found?

According to the Old Testament, Levitical services were an integral part of Israelite worship and the worship of the people to God. The Levites, from the tribe of Levi, were entrusted with many liturgical and sacrificial tasks in the Tabernacle and then the Temple of Jerusalem.
In the Book of Leviticus, there are many detailed prescriptions concerning the different types of sacrifices, offerings, and rituals that the Levites had to perform (Lv 1-7). The purpose of these acts of worship was to cleanse the people of their sins, to atone for them, and to reconcile them to God (Lv 16). As the exegete John Hartley points out, "the Levitical offices were crucial to allow communion between God and his people".1
In addition, the Levites were in charge of guiding the people in divine praise and worship, in particular through music, singing, and the recitation of the Psalms (1 Ch 15,16 - 22; 2 Ch 29,25-30). As the historian Martin Noth writes, "the Levites played a central role in the public expression of the faith of Israel".2
Thus, most of the exegetes agree that the Levitical offices were indeed a form of adoration and worship rendered to God by the people of Israel, in response to his covenant and his revelation. They were an essential way for the people to approach God and manifest their faith.
1 John E. Hartley, Leviticus, Biblical Commentary on Words (Dallas: Word, 1992), p. xxiv.
2 Martin Noth, The History of Israel, 2nd ed. (London: Adam and Charles Noir, 1960), p. 216.

Do you have any Scripture support for the assertion in your first paragraph?
